# installing pip on ubuntu 16.04... link not working

Tags: ubuntu, installation, pip

I was trying to install pip on my ubuntu desktop after sudo apt updating it 
But here's the problem.

```
 0 to upgrade, 12 to newly install, 0 to remove and 262 not to upgrade.
Need to get 1,303 kB/29.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 44.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Ign:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 python-pip-whl all 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.1
Ign:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 python-pip all 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.1
Ign:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 python-wheel all 0.29.0-1
Err:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 python-pip-whl all 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Err:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 python-pip all 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Err:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 python-wheel all 0.29.0-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-pip/python-pip-whl_8.1.1-2ubuntu0.1_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-pip/python-pip_8.1.1-2ubuntu0.1_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wheel/python-wheel_0.29.0-1_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I found out that the links that were throwing 404 errors were accessible if I remove the au. then it works. How can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Before installing anything always *update* your packages with:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then try

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-pycurl
```